# Remove last forward slash from href anchor

Tags: jquery, anchor, href

I have the following anchor situation:

```
<a href="https://example.com/my-account/#example/" class="anchor">...</a>
```

The above anchor gives me a jQuery conflict because of the slash of the `#` link. Because this is PHP generated I am looking for a **jQuery** Javascript solution to remove the last character of the `href` of this anchor. How do I do that?

The reason for this jquery conflict is, because #-links on my site are and should be scroll-to-id properties. So it scrolls to the id-element. This is a functionallity I cannot change how it's build, so the only solution I see is to remove the last `/` from the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

> The above anchor gives me a jQuery conflict because of the slash of the #-link

I'd suggest that you should fix that conflict as there is nothing inherently wrong with having a `/` in the fragment of the URL. If it's causing an error for you, then you need to fix your logic.

That being said, it's possible to do what you require by passing a function to `prop()` which removes any trailing slashes using a regex:

```js
$('.anchor').prop('href', function(i, href) {
  return href.replace(/\/$/, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com/my-account/#example/" class="anchor">...</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have explained why this is a jQuery conflict.

Comment: .replace gives me a jQuery Uncaught TypeError.

Comment: In which case I don't think you've copied the code above properly. Could you show me what code causes that error

Comment: It's a wordpress site that uses library v1.12.4, you have 3.3.1.

Comment: That makes zero difference to this method call. I've updated the answer with that version of jQuery anyway

Comment: I noticed a mistake in pointing to the right element, sorry! It works

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) method with a callback which iterates over the elements internally where callback holds old value as the second argument and it will update with the returned value.

```
$('.anchor').attr('href', (_, href) => href.slice(0, -1));
```

```js
$('.anchor').attr('href', (_, href) => href.slice(0, -1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com/my-account/#example/" class="anchor">...</a>
```

Comment: .slice gives me a jQuery Uncaught TypeError.

Comment: I noticed a mistake in pointing to the right element, sorry! It works

Answer (score 0):

If you have to change it at the Javascript side, you could split the string, pop the last element off, and rejoin it... (this assumes that the last character will ALWAYS be `/`, you'll need a sanity check if this is not always the case).

```js
let href = $('.anchor').prop('href').split("");
href.pop();
href = href.join("");

console.log(href);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com/my-account/#example/" class="anchor">...</a>
```