# Why are you unable to Array.prototype.pop.call() a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, prototype

As far as I understood, some Array methods can be used on strings by using the 
[call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method. While coming up with an answer for this question:

> [Remove last forward slash from href anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55935229/remove-last-forward-slash-from-href-anchor/55936928#55936928)

I came across an issue I wasn't expecting. I couldn't use `pop.apply()` on a string without receiving this error;

> "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot delete property '39' of [object
>   String]"

Why did this fail and why do only some array methods work?

```js
let href = $('.anchor').prop('href');
Array.prototype.pop.call(href);

console.log(href);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com/my-account/#example/" class="anchor">...</a>
```

Comment: Because strings are immutable. You should use `href = href.slice(0, -1)` or `= href.replace(/.$/s, "")` instead.

Comment: It says it right there in the error: `Cannot delete property '39' of [object String]`. When you call 'pop' on an array, presumably it finds the final index of the array, gets the value to return it, and deletes that index with something like `delete arr[39]`. But try calling `delete str[39]` on a string with 40 characters, see what happens.

Comment: The reason some array methods work is because they only call functions that ALSO exist on strings. This particular array method doesn't work because you cannot delete an index of a string.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, that makes sense. I shall be doing some research :) It's interesting that you can't make it return a new string, rather than try to mutate the existing one. I guess I need to figure out what `pop()` does under the hood (likely what TKoL says).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all array methods can be used on array. Those methods which try to mutate the string won't work. In Javascript strings are immutable. So methods like `push`, `pop`, `shift`, `splice` don't work.